# How to keep checksums the same for same codebase?

Tags: java, maven, checksum

OK - i get that checksums can change from build to build even with the same codebase - due to compile time date elements.

But is it possible to maintain the same checksum if the underlying codebase has not changed? Is there a simple way of doing this

Comment: It all depends on how you calculate the checksums.

Comment: Yes - so a method to calculate timestamps exempt of compile time